# Zeep gives an error query request too large. I have to pull ~100K records

Tags: python, zeep

I'm getting this error below. xml_huge_tree is set to True. Is there anything I can do to workaround this limitation?

Total rows fetched 99664 rows. Suggestive row fetch: less than 57852 rows

Thanks

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTvjG.png)

Answer (score 0):

If anybody runs into the same problem, that was actually AXL limit (~8MB) for a response, not zeep limitation. Ty!

Comment: So how did you solve the issue? Can you increase AXL response size?

Answer (score 0):

Use `skip`/`first` within your SQL query if you use thin-AXL. `listUser` method has it too.